# npm ERR! errno ENOENT

Tags: node.js, npm, enoent

when i search for npm version this error comes and i dont know how to solve this

```
C:\Users\User>npm -v
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! Callback called more than once.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-29T12_43_37_881Z-debug.log
6.14.11
```

Comment: maybe you have to reset your env variables..
can you provide the content of the log file C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-29T12_43_37_881Z-debug.log

Comment: Do you have Node installed?

Comment: yes i read somewhere to use 6.14.11 version

Comment: @josh yes how do i post whole content brother

Comment: @DavidFernándezOrtiz Yes i have download node properly

Comment: "enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file"
this means that npm cant find the file "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe". Can you confirm that the file doesn't exist?

Comment: @Josh yes i found node.exe at this location but no enoent named file was there

Comment: Are you sure that it is the exact same path?
By the way ENOENT is not a file name. Its the Error Code

Comment: @Josh yes it is in the exact same path it open node.exe